# ubuntu 16.04 .../ffmpeg error

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-sdk, ffmpeg

I want to install ubuntu sdk but when i tried to install  with this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk-ide
```

I have this error:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                     
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release»
no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Comment: this worked for me.. I did a "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" then did a "sudo rm *kirillshkrogalev*" to get rid of all the complaints I was getting when I was using the Application "Software Updater". That took me 6 months of sporatically trying to solve my problem I experenced after installing the kirillshkrogalev software package.

Answer (score 4):

The "404 Not Found" error message is telling you that the "FFmpeg next" PPA at https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next does not have an installation candidate for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial). To get rid of the warning, you can remove the `.list` file for the offending PPA in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. See [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/15003) if you are not sure how to do so.